# Sharepoint Multiple Item Creation Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I've been banging my head on this for a few days now, and seem to be no closer than before. Roughly it seems like the clientContext.executeQueryAsync is not working properly for creating multiple items in sharepoint. Here is the basic design.  I created a web part in my share point site that connects to an html page. The page is on the home.aspx of the site, that has the following content added to it via a content page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" x-undefined="" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/dre/SiteAssets/Javascript/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/dre/SiteAssets/Javascript/BatchControl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/dre/SiteAssets/Javascript/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/dre/SiteAssets/Javascript/PageLoader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/dre/SiteAssets/Javascript/BatchExecution.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){loadmasterpage();}, "sp.js")</script>
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="batch" style="visibility:hidden">
<button id="batchcontrol" onclick="ExecuteBatchControl()">Create DRE Records</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So it's a very simple piece of HTML. The PageLoader library loads the button after SP.js is loaded.

```
function loadmasterpage()
{
$(document).ready(function() {
    //alert("Here");
     $('#batch').css('visibility','visible');
});
}
```

That's all the web content does in the Home.aspx page.  It shows a simple HTML button. Now comes the baffling mystery.  So if I click the button the BatchControl library executes the following code:

```
function ExecuteBatchControl()
{
createListItem();
}

function createListItem() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Discrepancy Report');

    for(x=0;x<4;x++){
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    oListItem.set_item('Title', "B2Batch");   

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    }

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    //alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
    alert('Success');
  //  $("input[Title='Caller ID']").val("");
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

It creates the records, but the onQuerySucceeded function never executes.  If you remove the for...loop, it will execute, and it works fine.  Why doesn't the batch coding work.  It's almost like there is a stability issue with it, but I can't say.  No one seems to know the answer here. Is it because I hooked up my html page to a web content web part?  I am completely lost and baffled.  PLEASE I NEED HELP!!!!!!

Comment: are all records successfully created?  the way you have written it only the last one will be the current context, (it loads inside the for loop so is only relevant for the final parse of the for loop)   if your final one is failing for any reason, even if you have 400 others succeeding. then it will count as "failure"

Comment: Yeah I made mistake there with the client context, but in either case why would the onQuerySucceeded not fire off.  It should at least return one of the 2 alerts.

Comment: I don't think you need clientContext.load() when adding new items, executeQueryAsync should do. Load() is only needed when you want to receive data. Try to user load() for the list only, then add the items and just executeQueryAsync after.